# AWS System Manager GetParameters permission being implicitly denied

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-ssm, eksctl

I am trying to setup eksctl for eks but it throwing
`"Error: unable to determine AMI to use: error getting AMI from SSM Parameter Store: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam:::user/cnc is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.18/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id".`

The IAM Permission Policy I am using is

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:::parameter/*"
        }
    ]
```

I also tried using policy simulation for check the permissions , it is giving me "Implicitly Denied (No matching statement)"

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. The way I resolved it was by adding the region to the ssm resource. And also added a ssm:GetParameter like this:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":[
            "ssm:DescribeParameters"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":[
            "ssm:GetParameters",
            "ssm:GetParameter",
            "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:ca-central-1::parameter/*"
    }
]
```

If you notice I've added the region ca-central-1 and you should change it to your current region.

Answer (score 10):

For me, I was using `--with-decryption` for a SecureString. My Instance Profile also needed to have KMS rights to the `alias/parameter-store-key`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:111122223333:parameter/ITParameters/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had the same problem and the thing that was confusing for me was the error message didn't mention KMS at all.  It just said that I didn't have "ssm:GetParameter" permissions.  Arrrgghhh... IAM permission will be the death of me.

Comment: No doubt! We gotta support each other, cuz the AWS docs certainly won't

Answer (score 1):

Mine was in the other direction. I had `ssm:GetParameter`, and the error message was `AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action`, but implicitly the missing `ssm:GetParameters` was causing the request to be denied with a misleading error message.

Comment: I had the same issue. Was trying to use `ssm:GetParametersByPath` which apparently requires `ssm:GetParameters` as well. Lost a few hours on that one.... sigh

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lambda and do live edit of the policy attached to lambda’s role, it will not work. The policy update is not reflected until you switch to another role and switch back.

Also, for `GetParametersByPath` you have to provide the path, not path with `/*`. This is what worked for me:

```
statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
      "ssm:GetParameters",
      "ssm:GetParameter"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:0123456789:parameter:my-ssm-namespace"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to authorize the "ssm:GetParameter" action as well.

Comment: I have to also mention my resource id and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message as @plantbeard
but mine was related to capitalisation
I was using Serverless and taking the param name from the stage enviroment eg dev
but my parameter was called /Dev/param
renaming to /dev/param fixed it for me

Comment: This is a comment about another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71460789/ but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who still has issues, I was receiving the same error for my Lambda function:

"AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/[role-name]-role-xxxxxx/[lambda-function-name] is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:xxxxxx:parameter/[parameter_path1]/[parameter_pathx] because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action",

I found that on the policies page
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home#/policies

I needed to add the rule to a "Customer managed" Type Policy Named
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (I think someone else created this though and I just added on to it)

That looked like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:parameter/[parameter_path1]/[parameter_pathx]"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: AWS Policies]