# What are the minimal permissions required to GET parameters from AWS SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have tried setting up a permissions policy granting ssm:GetParameter and ssm:GetParameters to a role, but I get that error that "ssm:GetParameter is not allowed for this role". The only way I've found to eliminate the error is to grant ssm:* however I'd like to keep my permissions to a minimum. What am I missing here?

failing permission (account_id obscured):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:{redacted}:parameter/*"
    }
]
}
```

working permission:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ssm:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:{redacted}:parameter/*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Are you declaring a specific resource on policy? Maybe the ARN is incorrect. If you show the complete IAM Policy it would be helpful

Comment: What is your current policy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS System Manager GetParameters permission being implicitly denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653103/aws-system-manager-getparameters-permission-being-implicitly-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
"Action": [ 
  "ssm:GetParameter",
  "ssm:GetParameters",
  "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
]
```

If that does not help, allow "ssm:DescribeParameters".